# Unable to click the right to left DrawerLayout items

Tags: android, xml, listview, drawerlayout

I have an activity that displays a drawer layout when a menu item is clicked thus its direction is from right to left. I manage to display the navigation menu using the following code.

```
public class Forecast_details extends ActionBarActivity implements OnChartValueSelectedListener {

....
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //return false;
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if(id==R.id.Options){

            if (mDrawerlayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.END)){
                   mDrawerlayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);

               }else
                   mDrawerlayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

My Navigation drawer contains a static list so I did not bother to make a listview out of it as seen below,

[image]

However I cannot click my items inside the Drawer Layout, or anything in the view even v4.widget.DrawerLayout  in my xml is unclickable. Below is the two xml file that I used.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>
       <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_right"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:clickable="true">

           <include layout="@layout/nav_drawer_right" />

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2.36" >

             ....

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

nav_drawer_right.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView_right"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="#2c3e50"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_fragment2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp" >

        </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout_menuconatiner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_forward"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/darkblue"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="SendClick"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_forward" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3dip"
                    android:background="@color/separatorcolor"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:paddingRight="2dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_request"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/darkblue"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_request" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3dip"
                    android:background="@color/separatorcolor"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:paddingRight="2dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_reloadvnet"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/darkblue"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_updatevnet" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3dip"
                    android:background="@color/separatorcolor"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:paddingRight="2dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_reloadvsms"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/darkblue"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_updatevsms" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3dip"
                    android:background="@color/separatorcolor"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:paddingRight="2dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_feedback"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/darkblue"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_feedback" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3dip"
                    android:background="@color/separatorcolor"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:paddingRight="2dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Please help.. I tried a lot of things to make it work like using a listview instead but I still have no luck.. please do help, Im new at using drawer layout so there may be some more things I need to know.. Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

To prevent return `OnClickListener` to parent layout require set `android:clickable="true"` in drawerLayout container.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_right"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">       

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2.36" >

             ....

        </ScrollView>

        <include layout="@layout/nav_drawer_right" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_drawer_right.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView_right"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="end"
android:background="#2c3e50"
android:paddingTop="20dp" >

   ....

</ScrollView>
```

in your Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout= (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_right);
    ScrollView sV = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);

    sV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("drawer click >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        }
    });

  }
}
```